# Is it necessary to register a new waker every time Future::poll is called?

Tags: rust, async-await, future, rust-tokio

I am making my own channel implementation, but `std::task::Context` doesn't make it clear how the waker was generated.

My fake code:

```
struct MyAtomicWaker {
    lock: SpinLock,
    is_waked: AtomicBool,
    waker: std::task::Waker, 
}

struct WeakAtomicWaker (Weak<MyAtomicWaker>)

impl MyAtomicWaker {
    fn is_waked(&self) -> bool {}
    fn weak(self: Arc<MyAtomicWaker>) -> WeakAtomicWaker;
    fn cancel(&self) {}  // nullify WeakAtomicWaker, means the waker is not waked by a future
}

impl WeakAtomicWaker {
    fn wake(self) {}  // upgrade to arc and can wake only once when waker not cancelled
}

struct ReceiveFuture<T> {
    waker: Option<Arc<MyAtomicWaker>>,
}

impl<T> Drop for ReceiveFuture<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(waker) = self.waker.take() {  waker.cancel(); }
    }
}

impl<T> Future for ReceiveFuture<T> {
    type Output = Result<(), SendError<T>>;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, ctx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let _self = self.get_mut();
        if _self.waker.is_none() {
          let my_waker = _self.reg_waker(ctx.waker().clone()); // wrap the waker with Arc, store it inside _self, and send the weak ref to other side of channel
          _self.waker.replace(my_waker);
        }

        // do some polling
        match _self.recv.try_recv() {
            Ok(item)=>{ 
                if let Some(waker) = _self.waker.take() {
                    waker.cancel();
                }
                return Poll::Ready(item);  //canncel my waker and ready
            },
            Err(TryRecvError)=>{
               if let Some(waker) = _self.waker.as_ref() {
                   if waker.is_wake() { // the waker is triggered but it's a false alarm, should make a new one.
                       let my_waker = self.reg_waker(ctx.waker().clone()); 
                       _self.waker.replace(my_waker);
                   } else { // the waker has not trigger, we do not have to make a new one ?
                   }
               }
               return Poll::Pending;    
          },
          Err(...)
        }
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to register a new waker every time `poll()` is called? In my code, there's a lot of timeouts and looping selects due to the combination of different futures.

I have a little experiment that works [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0bc946de7f1f968e7af34715439824ae), but I'm not sure whether it will always work fine for both Tokio and async-std in various settings.

In my production code, I register a new waker and cancel the old waker in every `poll()` call. I don't know whether it is safe to only register a  waker the first time and reuse it on the next polls.

Given the following order:

1. `f.reg_waker(waker1)`
   `f.poll()` gets `Poll::Pending`
2. combined future (or future::select) wakeup due to other future selecting, but waker1 has not woken up.
   `f.poll()` gets `Poll::Pending`
3. some outsider call waker1.wake();

will `waker1.wake()` guarantee to wake up `f` after that?

---

I'm asking this because:

1. I have a `Stream` that multiplexes multiple receiving channels
2. My MPMC and MPSC channel implementations are lockless. Some channels inside a multiplex selection may be used as a close notification channel and seldom gets message. When I'm polling it a lot (say a million times), it will lead to a million waker thrown to the other side (which looks like a memory leak). Canceling previous wakers produced in the same future without lock is more complex logic than an implementation with lock
3. For these reasons, I have a waker canceling solution that leads to fairness problem, which needs to be avoided as much as possible

I'm not interested in what the book states, or what the API laws declare; I'm only interested in how the low level is implemented. Show some code why this works or why this does not work would be helpful. I code to implement product; if necessary I will stick to a specified dependency or do some hacking in order to get the job done until I have a better way.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Given the fact that "a waker can be waked in parallel of `Future::poll`.

Counter-evidence:  Presuming every time a waker must be `clone()` and re-registered in order for this future to wake up properly, this will make previous waker invalid, so it's not possible for "concurrent wake up from different thread, e.g. `future::select` block".  The conclusion is not true, so it counter-proves this statement:

"A waker is always valid from the time starting from `ctx.waker().clone()` until `waker.wake()`". This serves my motive. waker is not needed to reset every time, if it's not used to woken yet.

In addition to investigate tokio waker implementation,  all RawWaker produce by ctx.waker.clone() is just a ref_count to a manual drop memory entry on the heap, if wakers clone outside prevent the ref_count dropping zero, the real waker entry always exists.

Comment: After a day of long run with my storage engine under load ,  with multiple Timeout & future select & manual implemented future of multiple channel,  the result seams good, no hanging nor request timeout is observed,

Comment: now I'm pretty sure these assumption is stable with tokio, verified by code and tests, closing this thread now

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is required to re-set the waker each time. [`Future::poll`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) states (emphasis mine):

> Note that on multiple calls to `poll`, **only the `Waker` from the `Context` passed to the most recent call** should be scheduled to receive a wakeup.

See also:

- [Why do I not get a wakeup for multiple futures when they use the same underlying socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60964709/155423)
- [Is it valid to wake a Rust future while it's being polled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59974095/155423)

Comment: Thanks for editing my post. There's still interest for me if the answer is no , I have now try removing the re-register part of the code and test it on, because it will speed up the execution and avoid some complex concurrency model because I'm wrapping up crossbeam channel in future enviroment.

Comment: @frostyplanet I'm not following your comment. My answer states that you **must** use the new waker that was passed in. Doing otherwise will lead to cases where the wakeup notification will be lost and then the entire future may never be polled again.

Comment: I suspect the second time poll context to the same future is the same as the context the first time (or ctx.waker.clone() will gets waker points to the same instant) . there's pain canceling the first waker due to I'm hoping it complete lockless.  In some premier test after changing the production code seems ok. Just need a long time testing to be sure before look into the low level implementation.

Comment: @frostyplanet I don't understand why you'd ask the question if you are going to ignore the answer just because you don't like it...

Comment: Indeed I am looking for a solid answer of No ... Because my previous code is base on a possible Yes

Comment: After removing the re-register part for an hour looking good for now, I will run a couple of days, maybe weaks to confirm.

Comment: @frostyplanet to reiterate, it doesn't matter how much you test if you deliberately break the API contract. Any conforming executor / future can rely on the documented behavior of API and your code will stop working. You'd have to vet every possible version of every permutation of combinators and executors, including those that aren't yet released!

Comment: To be really exceedingly clear here: The answer is, unequivocally 'No, you can't do that'. If you're having a hard time understanding that through the detailed technical explanations, then it's only because Shep is helpfully providing a bunch of technical reasons. It does not change the basic fact here: There is **no** way to do this safely, because it *directly violates* the API contract.

Comment: I think I have not voliate the API, because I only clone the waker once (not multiple), store an Arc of MyWaker inside my current future, and make a Weak for outsider to wake up. before every poll, the state inside MyWaker can tell wether MyWaker is woken already.

Comment: to make question more clear, I have edited my fake code, the real part of code is some what simular to the rust playground example, I will publish my channel implementation once it's provent in production

Comment: Are you reading a different API definition than I am? The API clearly states that the waker must be from the context used in the most recent call to `poll`.

Keeping an old waker around because you think it's a good idea, and using that waker instead of the one from the most recent context, is a violation of the API contract. If you can prove that the context is the same one as from a previous call, and it gives the same waker, then you can use that waker. But there's no way around checking those conditions, so you might as well get the waker each time.

Comment: @Zarenor yeah I can live with that risk, since i'm not writing generic code, I can understand that this is deny by the document to prevent people write bad code, but I can handle myself